# Implementing a truncated regression for a normal distribution in R

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, truncated-normal-distribution, truncated-distributions

I'm not a statistician but I'm working with some experimental psychology data. I have a distribution of responses on a -4 to 4 scale. Usually, these type of variables is treated as continuous. I have to model this variable based on some predictors (experimental factors).
I'm thinking about different ways to model it:

- Linear Mixed-Effect Model (for repeated measure)
- Ordinal Regression (if I consider the variable as an ordered factor)

However, I've heard about the possibility to use a Truncated Normale as target distribution. Could be useful in this case? Is there a way to do it in R?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a Beta mixed effects model. In this model the response data are in the $(0, 1)$ interval. To fulfill this requirement, you could transform your original data $Y$ into $Y^* = (Y + 4) / 8$ and fit the Beta mixed model for $Y^*$.

You could fit this model in R using the [**GLMMadaptive**](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/) package. For examples, look [here](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Custom_Models.html#beta-mixed-effects-model).